# Databinding to Windows 8 ListView

Tags: javascript, html, windows, data-binding, microsoft-metro

I'm having massive problems with databinding to a ListView in a Windows 8 app using Javascript.

Inside the "activated" event on default.js I have written some code to get some data from a web service and push it into an array. This bit works OK and the array is populated.

The problem I have is that the app won't recognise the data. I have this code in a page called inspections.html:

```
data-win-options="{itemTemplate: select('#imageTextListCollectionTemplate'),
                                itemDataSource: dataList.dataSource,
                                layout: {type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout}}
```

and then in the "activated" event I declare:

```
var dataList = new Array();
```

and push the data from the web service into this array. But at runtime I get an error that says something along the lines of "can't find dataSource on undefined dataList".

I've done some of the examples on the MS website and in one of them it creates a dummy dataset and references it from a namespace. I kinda think that what I'm missing here is a namespace too but I don't know what the namespace for default.js is. Or maybe I'm wrong and it's something totally different.

Please help - this is so fundamental (and should be easy) but I can't get my head around it.

Comment: I don't know the syntax for JS Metro, but your syntax just looks wrong -- if `dataList` is an `Array`, then it's not going to contain a `dataSource` property ... is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to create datalist in HTML or javascript?

It seems you want to create it from JavaScript. Assuming that you have already pushed your data into array from your webservice, you only need to call:

`var dataList = new WinJS.Binding.List(array);`

now accessing `dataList.dataSource` is perfectly valid.

Also, to create the datalist you don't always need an array. You could probably start with an empty list and then keep inserting data directly into the data list from web services, like:

```
var dataList = new WinJS.Binding.List([]);
dataList.push(value1);
dataList.push(value2);
```

...

Hope it helps. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting troubled by assigning datasource in HTML side

Prefer js side like

```
 var list = new WinJS.Binding.List(array here);
 listView.itemDataSource = list.dataSource;
```

by using this you can easily go through the data which you are binding to ListView.